# iOS screenshot failed with OpenGL

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot

This is my **code**:

```
@implementation UIView (LCExtension)

- (UIImage *)screenshotWithRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, rect)];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}

@end
```

And I set a breakpoint at here:

[image: code]

Run:

- This is **view-self**: (picture from OpenGL Rendering)

  [image: view-self]
- This is **generated picture**:

  [image]

Why it's a black picture?

Answer (score 1):

When working with OpenGL (ES), yeah, I assuming you are using OpenGL ES because you have a UIView category, remember that capture screen right before presenting your renderbuffers. Once you or subclass of GLKViewController present renderbuffer, it become front framebuffer, then the screen framebuffer become back framebuffer, which gives you nothing except the color you set with `glClearColor`.

```
[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:]
```

Here is a sample code for capturing screen.

```
- (UIImage *)createImageFromFramebuffer {
    GLint params[10];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, params);
    int width = params[2];
    int height = params[3];
    const int renderTargetWidth = width;
    const int renderTargetHeight = height;
    const int renderTargetSize = renderTargetWidth*renderTargetHeight * 4;

    uint8_t* imageBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(renderTargetSize);
    glReadPixels(params[0], params[1],
             renderTargetWidth, renderTargetHeight,
             GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageBuffer);

    const int rowSize = renderTargetWidth*4;

    CGDataProviderRef ref = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, imageBuffer, renderTargetSize, NULL);
    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(renderTargetWidth, renderTargetHeight, 8, 32, rowSize,
                                CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault, ref,
                                NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    uint8_t* contextBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(renderTargetSize);
    memset(contextBuffer, 0, renderTargetSize);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(contextBuffer, renderTargetWidth, renderTargetHeight, 8, rowSize,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(iref),
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, renderTargetHeight);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, renderTargetWidth, renderTargetHeight), iref);
    CGImageRef outputRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:outputRef];

    CGImageRelease(outputRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(ref);

free(contextBuffer);
    free(imageBuffer);
    return image;
}
```